# emacs arglist-cont-nonempty to use 4 spaces, not a tab

Tags: emacs, indentation

So I am trying to follow the old Sun "cstyle" standard, then Solaris, now IllumOS. They use tabs pretty much everywhere, that is fine. But there is one case where it should have same indentation, plus 4 spaces.

If I set `(c-set-offset 'arglist-cont-nonempty ' 4)` I get the correct placement, but because 4 spaces is a tab, emacs puts a tab there. If I use 3 or 5, they are spaces. Is there someway I can quote a "space" to have literal 4 spaces without convertion, or, perhaps temporarily, disable tabs-everywhere?

rest of .emacs is here:

```
(setq default-tab-width 4)
(setq tab-width 4)
(setq-default c-indent-tabs-mode t    
            c-indent-level 4       
            c-argdecl-indent 0      
            c-tab-always-indent t
            backward-delete-function nil)  
  (c-add-style "my-c-style" '((c-continued-statement-offset 4)))
  (defun my-c-mode-hook ()
  (c-set-style "my-c-style")
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open '0)
  (c-set-offset 'inline-open '+)
  (c-set-offset 'block-open '+)
  (c-set-offset 'brace-list-open '+)  
  (c-set-offset 'arglist-cont-nonempty ' 4)
  (c-set-offset 'case-label '+))      
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to use spaces instead of tabs when indenting, put the
>   following in your .emacs file:
>
> ```
> (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
> ```
>
> You may also customize the `indent-tabs-mode` variable instead,
>   obviously. If you want to remove tabs in an existing file, mark the
>   whole buffer using `C-x h` and use `M-x untabify`

see [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NoTabs)

Comment: No, they use tabs everywhere as I said, but this one case arglist-cont-nonempty it needs to be 4 spaces.